# Formula inserted by code in string array is not calculating

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a problem that formulas are not recalculated if I add them in one step from a string field.

My point is to add various complex formula calculations in one step to multiple columns.

None of this works:

- automatically calculated formulas are switched on
- I've tried
- ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General" - doesnt work
- I've tried
  Application.Volatile - doesnt work Recording text to columns and
  assign cells to "general"

  ```
  Sub AddActualsSum2()


    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXXX")
    Call ProtectSheet(ws, False)

    Dim r, s, monthRange, monthRange01, monthRangeDynamic As Range
    Dim MonthLock, i, LockActuals As Integer
    Dim c As String
    Dim StartActualsDate, PlanDate As Date





    Set monthRange = Range("_ActualsY02M01:_ActualsY02M12")
    Set monthRangeDynamic = Range("_ActualsSumMonthY2")


    Dim varData(1 To 12) As String

    Call ProtectSheet(ws, False)
    For i = 1 To 12
        varData(i) = "=1+2"

    Next



    Debug.Print "Format: " & monthRange(1).NumberFormat
    Debug.Print "Value: " & monthRange(1).Value
    Debug.Print "Formula: " & monthRange(1).Formula

    monthRange.Formula = varData





  End Sub
  ```

The result is that the formula = 1 + 2 is everywhere

after clicking in the formula line, the formula is already calculated correctly.

Comment: Is there a purpose to `varData`? You can simply do `monthRange.Value = "=1+2"`, `monthRange.Value2 = "=1+2"` or `monthRange.Formula = "=1+2"` to get `3` for `.Value`, `.Value2` and `.Text`, and to get `"=1+2"` for `.Formula`, for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

When writing the array as a block, Excel treats the values are strings (which they are), rather than formulae.

Put the formula writing inside the loop, like

```
  For i = 1 To 12
    varData(i) = "=1+2"
    monthRange.Cells(i, 1).Formula = varData(i)
  Next
```

Also, your variable declarations are wrong. VBA requires each variable to have a type, otherwise they are Variants by default. For example:

```
Dim MonthLock, i, LockActuals As Integer
```

Should be:

```
Dim MonthLock As Range, i As Integer, LockActuals As Integer
```